# Error in generic code

Tags: java

I am getting this error `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to E"` in the last line of the `pop()` method.

**Node**

```
public class Node<E> {  
    E item;
    Node next;

    Node(E item) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = null;
    }

    Node(E item, Node next) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

**Stack**

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Stack<E> {
    private Node head;
    private int size;

    Stack() {
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void push(E item) {
        head = new Node (item, head);
        size++;
    }

    public E pop() throws NoSuchElementException {
        Node nodeToBePopped;
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        nodeToBePopped = head;
        head = head.next;
        size--;
        return nodeToBePopped.item;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why that error occurs despite item being declared as type E in the Node class. Why do I have to make an explicit cast in this instance?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code when you ask questions - look at the preview before you hit post, and make sure it looks like the kind of question you'd want to read.

Comment: (And please use spaces rather than tabs for indentation.)

Comment: Sorry, Jon. I'll make sure next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem in `Stack<E>`:

```
private Node head;
```

and likewise later:

```
Node nodeToBePopped;
```

And in `Node<E>` itself:

```
Node next;
```

You're using the *raw type* `Node` here, so all the generics are lost, effectively. See the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Raw%20Types) for more information about raw types.

Just change the variable types to `Node<E>` and it should be fine.

I'd also recommend using `private` fields, and only declaring local variables at the point of first use - so your `pop` method would become:

```
public E pop() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    Node<E> nodeToBePopped = head;
    head = head.next;
    size--;
    return nodeToBePopped.item;
}
```

Or in fact, just find the value to return from `head` before you change what `head` refers to:

```
public E pop() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (size == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    E previousHeadValue = head.item;
    head = head.next;
    size--;
    return previousHeadValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jon. Yes, I've been thinking about the private fields. How do I manage to keep the next and item variables private in Node and still do what I'm doing in Stack?

Answer (score 0):

Change the types of `head` and `nodeToBePopped` to `Node<E>`

This is because you have not specified that `Stack<E>` will have only elements of type `Node<E>`

Similarly change the `push` method and also the `next` variable in `Node<E>`.